# From which version of ag-grid, filtering was supported? I am unable to add filtering with ag-grid version 17.1.1

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to setup the normal column filter text for which i have added a filter property in column definition and set it to  filter: true. But still the filter is not shown.

Comment: Check the version release docs of ag-grid and you'll find the answer. (BTW I don't have it otherwise given off course). If its not in the release docs update your question with that knowledge.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/17.1.1/documentation-main/documentation.php - I think filter was supported in 17.1.1. If you are facing any issue, reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz. See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get.